# Python use request to login

Tags: python, web-scraping, python-requests

my target is to login within this website:

```
http://www.six-swiss-exchange.com/indices/data_centre/login.html
```

And once logged, access the page:

```
http://www.six-swiss-exchange.com/downloads/indexdata/composition/close_smic.csv
```

To do this, I am using `requests` (password and email are unfortunately fake there):

```
import requests

login_url = "http://www.six-swiss-exchange.com/indices/data_centre/login_en.html"
dl_url = "http://www.six-swiss-exchange.com/downloads/indexdata/composition/close_smic.csv"

with requests.Session() as s:
    payload = {
        'username':'GG@gmail.com',
        'password':'SummerTwelve'
    }

    r1 = s.post(login_url, data=payload)
    r2 = s.get(dl_url, cookies=r1.cookies)
    print 'You are not allowed' in r2.content
```

And the script always returns `False`. I am using `Chrome` and `inspect` to check the form to fill, this is the result of inspect when I manually login:

```
    payload = {
        'viewFrom':'viewLOGIN',
        'cugname':'swxindex',
        'forward':'/indices/data_centre/adjustments_en.html',
        'referer':'/ssecom//indices/data_centre/login.html',
        'hashPassword':'xxxxxxx',
        'username':'GG@gmail.com',
        'password':'',
        'actionSUBMIT_LOGIN':'Submit'
   }
```

I tried with this, with no result, where `XXXXX` is the encoded value of `SummerTwelve`... I clearly do not know how to solve this out! Maybe by mentionning the headers ? The server could reject script request?

Comment: Where is it returning false?

Comment: Here: `print 'You are not allowed' in r2.content`

Comment: Have you tried  adding a user-agent?

Comment: Yes i tried adding `headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'}` in    `r1 = c.post(login_url, data=payload, headers=headers)` and `r2 = c.get(dl_url, headers=headers, cookies=r1.cookies)`

Comment: The thing is that the `dl_url` is not protected but I need to authentification so that a download window pops up ... do not know if request is appropriate there ...

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem today, and in my case the problem was starting the website interaction with a 'post' command. Due to this, I did not have a valid session cookie which I could provide to the website, and therefore I got the error message "your browser does not support cookies".

The solution was to load the login-page once using `get`, then send the login-data using `post`:

```
s = requests.Session()

r = s.get(url_login)
r = s.post(url_login, data=logindata)
```

My `logindata` corresponds to your `payload`.

With this, the session cookie is managed by the session and you don't have to care about it.